# How to disable other tabs while loading any tab in bootstreap3

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using following tab to load remote tab.

Here I want to load first tab default(after loading the page)  and while loading any tab other tabs should be disabled.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-pills"  id="tab">
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com" data-target="#Google" class="media_node active span" id="info_tab" data-toggle="tabList" rel="tooltip"> Google </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.yahoo.com"  data-target="#Yahoo" class="media_node span" id="posts_tab" data-toggle="tabList" rel="tooltip"> Yahoo</a>
   </li>
</ul>
   <div class="tab-content">
   <div class="tab-pane active" id="Google">Click to load</div>                  <div class="tab-pane" id="Yahoo">Loading</div>
    </div>
```

How to achive this?